# Math issue dividing view in subviews

Tags: math, objective-c-category

I have a math question in order to make some objective-c code for my app.

I have n images with fixed dimensions. I would like to divide these images over a view in rows and columns. The view has dimensions x / y. I want the images to have the maximum size (surface) although their dimensions are fixed.

I think this is a math problem I probably learned in school but I forgot.

I contemplated writing a bit of trial and error code but there must be a more elegant solution.

If the surface is square the solution is simply the square root. But this is not always the case.

Cheers
Nick

Comment: This is an example of a difficult, interesting class of problems called "combinatorial optimization". A general solution is probably far too much work. I think you can devise a special case without too much trouble. On one extreme you can put all images in one row, at the other you can put them all in one column. In between you can have #rows <= max rows and #cols <= max cols. So there aren't too many combinations to try. Just enumerate all (max rows) times (max cols) possibilities, throw out the ones which don't work, and then evaluate any remaining to find the best. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Follow up questions should probably be directed to math.stackexchange.com or cs.stackexchange.com. There might also be an algorithms.stackexchange.com but that might be wishful thinking on my part.